# Add string to selected column name php

Tags: php, sql

I use PHP to take data from  2 tables like this:

```
      <?php
$connStr ='odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' . 'Dbq=C:\accessfile.accdb;';

$dbh = new PDO($connStr);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "SELECT * from (SELECT id AS myid, Email FROM `NEW`";
        $sql .= " UNION ALL SELECT ID AS myid, `E mail` FROM `OLD`)";
        $sql .= " ORDER BY myid ASC";

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

    $params=array();
    $sth->execute($params);

    while ($row = $sth->fetch()) {
    //display data here
    }
        ?>
```

Issue 1: When i try to add alias to id, i get an error to the sql statement.
The error i get is this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => IMSSP 
        [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP 
        [1] => -14 
        [code] => -14 
        [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. 
    )
)
```

Issue 2: Knowing that i cannot change the tables at all, i need to my row results to know from which table data came, so i need to add a string to the id column like this maybe:

```
SELECT 'new_'+id AS myid, ..... FROM ...   OR like this
SELECT CONCAT('New_', id) AS myid, ..... FROM
```

but none of the above work for me. The result when i try to fetch a row like this:

```
<?php echo $row['myid']; ?>
```

to have new_1, new_2 etc or old_1, old_2 etc

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What SQL error you get? Give us exact error you see.

Comment: I get this: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. ) ).

Comment: Give us full code, especially where you call `sqlsrv_execute`.

Comment: Just did. The data is retrieved from access database file

Comment: please add code of the actual sql call. which sql library are you using?

Comment: `E mail FROM OLD`. Is it E mail or Email, Is there any mistake on question? Because on using `UNION` columns should be same on both tables.

Comment: concatenate the string using `php`, not by using `sql`

Comment: E mail is how column is registered in the access file. No mistake. I am adding full code with driver loaded in 1 min

Comment: I think Column name should be same for tables using in `UNION` query. You have used it on `id` AS `myid`

Comment: Column names do not have to be the same as soon as i use aliases because for the data fetching i use aliases

Comment: Was there any error on my query? hope you may get the data propery. for me a similar query was fine.

Comment: i get a blank page with your solution

Comment: ok, im adding that query over here. I donot know why its blank.
`SELECT * from (SELECT `NEW`.`id` AS myid, `NEW`.`Email` AS Email FROM `NEW` UNION ALL SELECT `OLD`.`ID` AS myid, `OLD`.`E mail` AS Email FROM `OLD`) AS GENERATED_TABLE ORDER BY `GENERATED_TABLE`.`myid` ASC`

Comment: To differentiate between the tables, you could just add a static expression, e.g. `SELECT ..., "new" AS source_table FROM NEW ...` and `SELECT ..., "old" AS source_table FROM OLD ...`.

Comment: Again Sinto, query brings blank page.  Also, i don't know if it matters somehow, but ID column from access database file is autonumber column. Is there a change that there is a conflict for autonumber columns and aliases?? And also CONCAT does not work at all. Is there another expression when using odbc drivers?

Comment: Till now Paul's solution is the best i could use and then to check if i have old or new to place id into a value with my desired string.

Comment: What about 
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CAST(CONCAT( 'New_', `NEW`.`id` ) AS CHAR) AS myid, `NEW`.`Email` AS Email FROM `NEW` UNION ALL SELECT CAST(CONCAT( 'Old_', `OLD`.`ID` ) AS CHAR) AS myid, `OLD`.`E mail` AS Email FROM `OLD`) AS GENERATED_TABLE ORDER BY `GENERATED_TABLE`.`myid` ASC

Comment: Not working either. I get error when using concat and cast

Answer (score 0):

I cannot understand your **issue 1**, but the answer to **issue 2** is that you can add string with the concatenation sign (`||`) in your SQL statement. If you like to mention the string with data, use a query like this:

```
select Column_Name || ' tablename ' AS temp_name from table;
```

Comment: Sorry Fahad, the format you have is invalid. I remind you that query is inside a php variable.

Comment: SELECT * from (SELECT 'strng' || id AS myid, Email FROM `NEW`";
         UNION ALL SELECT 'string' || ID AS myid, `E mail` FROM `OLD`)";
         ORDER BY myid";

Comment: and when you are using orderby clause ASC is by default .no need to add it .